Default page set in web.config is not captured by IIS website
I am trying to take an existing copy of a IIS website folder, put in a new folder and run a new site from IIS. But the default page set in web.config file is not picked up by IIS... When I type the site url in the browser, only the directory listing appears. (But that can be switched-off by turning off the directory listing option) I have not changed the default page setting for this website.
Below is the web.config setting
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/signin" timeout="600" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>

--UPDATED--
The applicationHost.config file
 <applicationPools>
    <add name="student2" autoStart="true" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
    <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" />
    </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>

<site name="student2" id="20" serverAutoStart="true">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="student2">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Websites\student2" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52000:" />
    </bindings>
</site>


You have to edit the question and reveal the <sites> tag from IIS applicationHost.config file at least. The snippet you shared does not control default page either.

@LexLi updated the content with the IIS applicationhost.config  file But I cant find a related setting concerning the default start page there.

The redirection workflow of forms authentication is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs. All necessary settings are included so you need to review which ones you missed.

Please ensure default document is enabled in IIS:

Open IIS Manager.
Select the site you want to configure.
Double-click on the Default Document feature in the IIS section.
Ensure that the page you want to set as the default (e.g. index.html) is listed. If not, click Add and enter the correct default page.
Restart the website or do an IIS reset after making changes.


Actually it not the index.html or default.html/asp pages in the  "default documents" setting which I want to set, but the  "~/account/signin" which I mentioned above in the web.config file. My issue is that the same settings set in one website works fine, but not in the second IIS website which I created

Your applicationHost.config file configuration looks basically correct, but the problem you are experiencing may be related to some IIS configuration or environment mismatch. please confirm that the physical path C:\Websites\student2 is correct and there is a default document or corresponding startup page under this folder.
Check the read/write permissions of the folder and make sure that the identity of the application pool ApplicationPoolIdentity has read permissions for this directory.
